# How to add element after every post in the loop, but not the last one

Tags: loop

I have a pretty common loop:

```
global $wp_query, $wpdb;
if ( have_posts() )
{
    while ( have_posts() )
    {
        the_post();

        get_template_part(
             'template_parts/content'
            ,get_post_format()
        );
    }
}
else
{
    get_template_part( 'no_results' );
}
```

Now I need to add (for example) a `<hr />` after each single post, but not the last one.

How would I determine if I currently got the second to last post in the current loop?

Note: This should work for paged loops as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another possibility:

```
if( $wp_query->current_post < $wp_query->post_count-1 ) echo '<hr />';
```

Comment: Not that bad :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's pretty easy:

```
( $wpse_counter = count( $wp_query->posts ) ) && ++$GLOBALS['wpdb']->wpse_post_in_loop < $wpse_counter AND print "<hr />";
```

Calling the global with `$GLOBALS['wpdb']` will allow modifying the global itself. Therefore I use a custom, prefixed property named `wpse_post_in_loop` to not in interfere with core settings, properties, etc.

The above line is just for elegance. If you want to keep this fast, it's better to do the `count()` part in front of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wp_query, $wpdb;
if( have_posts() ) {
    $total_posts = $wp_query->found_posts;
    $i = 0;
    while( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        $i++;
        get_template_part(
                'template_parts/content'
                , get_post_format()
        );
        if( $i != $total_posts ) {
            echo '<hr />';
        }
    }
} else {
    get_template_part( 'no_results' );
}
```

It would be okay to remove $wpdb too because it is not being used anywhere in this example.